# create a relationship between node type a to either of two other node types neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

The goal is to point a relationship two other different node types within one query. Should be doable...

```
MATCH (a:person), (b:fruit|b:vegetable)
WHERE a.favorite_food = b.name
CREATE (a)-[r:likes]->(b)
```

This is what id think it would look like, but doesn't seem to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if I understand completely your question.

If you want that `(b)` matches with nodes that have `fruit` **OR** `vegetable` labels, you can use [labels()](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-labels) function in conjunction with [ANY](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/predicate/#functions-any).

```
MATCH (a:person), (b)
WHERE ANY(x IN ['fruit', 'vegetable'] WHERE x IN labels(b)) 
AND a.favorite_food = b.name
CREATE (a)-[r:likes]->(b)
```

If you want that `(b)` matches with nodes that have `fruit` **XOR** `vegetable` labels (that is: one and only one between these two labels), change from `any()` to [single()](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/predicate/#functions-single).

But if you want that `(b)` matches with nodes that have `fruit` **AND** `vegetable` labels, you can simply specify two labels in the same variable on matching, like this:

```
MATCH (a:person), (b:fruit:vegetable)
WHERE a.favorite_food = b.name
CREATE (a)-[r:likes]->(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to achieve, the simplest solution is to add an additional Food label to all the Fruit and Vegetable nodes.  Then you have a way to address both with a single label, (b:Food).

If you don't want to do that, you can use the LABELS() function to check if a particular label is present on each node.  But as has been mentioned by others, this will require scanning all of the nodes in the database.

Another solution is to do the checks in sequence, but collapse the query pipeline down using an aggregate function before moving to the next (to avoid cartesian products or having to collect distinct nodes.

Answer (score -1):

You need a migration script to add Neo4j relationships based on properties of your existing nodes. I suggest using the language of your choice to write the migration script in code that calls your Neo4j DB via the appropriate driver.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to Brunos [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46364106/6893866), you can use

```
MATCH (a:Person) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (f:fruit), (v:vegetable) 
WITH m, COLLECT(DISTINCT f)+COLLECT(DISTINCT v) as list
UNWIND list as b
CREATE UNIQUE (a)-[r:likes]->(b)
```

or

```
MATCH (a:Person) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (f:fruit)
CREATE UNIQUE (a)-[r:likes]->(f)
WITH a
OPTIONAL MATCH (v:vegetable)
CREATE UNIQUE (a)-[r:likes]->(v)
```

Which may be more performant based on your DB since it doesn't require an all node scan.

Comment: Using MATCH with both Fruit and Vegetable at the same time (as in the OPTIONAL MATCH lines above) will produce a cartesian product between Fruits and Vegetables.  As written, you'll end up creating many more relationships than you intend.  The first tries to get around this by collecting distinct nodes, but will require an UNWIND to function correctly.

Comment: @JonathanMarch forgot the unwind step. fixed both queries.